# Integration by parts (Differential Geometry)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying the proof of a theorem and I am stuck. It says that by integration by parts we get that:

For $g(t)$ a variation of Riemannian metrics wih $g'(0)=h,$

$$\int_{M} (-\Delta (tr h) + \delta^2 h)\;dV_g=0$$

where $\Delta$ is the rough Laplacian, and $\delta^2 h=\nabla^i \nabla^j h_{ij}$ is the double-divergence operator.

I don't understand how integration by parts imply that this integral is equal to zero.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are consequence of divergnece theorem: for any vector fields $X$ on $M$,

$$\int_M \text{div}(X) dV_g = 0. $$

(div is just $\delta$ in your question) The first term is zero as for all functions $f$,

$$\int_M \Delta f dV_g = \int_M \text{div} (\nabla f) dV_g = 0$$

while the second one, choose the vector fields to be

$$X_i = \nabla ^j h_{ij} $$

(Doing $F$/ $W$- Functional ^^?)

Comment: thank you! -Total scalar curvature functional.

Comment: Ah! You are right!